# Tag display does not show special tag CSS when filtering by tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, user-interface

If you filter a set of questions by a tag, the special tags: status-declined, status-completed, etc. does not show up with the CSS that differentiates them from other tags (i.e., they have the same coloring as the other tags).  Note I'm talking about the "related" tags display, not the "chosen" tags display.

Answer (score 1):

Have seen this when entering the highlighted tags in the interesting/ignore list. They come up as bland samey-samey. Won't flash their wares and coat of difference until you reload the page or move away from the page you're on while you're adding tags to your interest/ignore list.